# How can I update a large raster with new values in R with speed?

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster with 2332800 cells. Half of these cells are probably oceans and unneeded. I need to update these cells with new values. Right now I'm using a for loop and it takes a very long time:

Example:

```
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
df<-data.frame(ID = 1:100, values = runif(100))


for (i in 1:ncell(r)) {
  ifelse(i %in% df$ID,
         r[i]<-df$values[df$ID == i],
         NA
  )
}
```

With millions of cells this for loop is slow. I was thinking about using parallel processing but at the same time there might be something faster?

I also am stuck with the dataframe and cell_id query style unfortunately.

Perhaps someone has a workaround before I start playing around with the parallels and foreach package.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. ALL-CAPS in titles are difficult to read. Instead of attracting positive attention, they are more likely to attract downvotes and look-away.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a single, focused question.

Comment: @Vince I've edited the title to lower case. If you've got edit privs its better to do that than just complain in a comment. I should have done this when I first saw this Q yesterday, but I was busy answering it.

Comment: I would reccomend using the terra library. Then you have a native 'terra::ifel' function negating the need for a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-liner would be:

```
r[] = df$values[match(r[], df$ID)]
```

This uses `match` to look up the `df$values` entry for each `r[]` value matching the `df$ID`.

Note that `r[]` is pretty much the same as `values(r)`.

This might struggle if you raster is too large to hold in RAM, but 2.3M isn't so big for that. Runs in a blink of an eye on a 2000x1000 raster on my laptop.

Check on a small example first.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This works great! Switched over to `terra` as well and it's a lot faster. Thank you for your time!